# The Tzadik, The Nations and the Geulah: the chiddush of Rabbi Mordechai Rottenberg

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, talmud-yerushalmi, messianic-redemption, shalos-shevuos

[Rabbi Mordechai Rottenberg](https://www.geni.com/people/Markus-Rottenberg/6000000004955321754), Rabbi of Antwerp (1872-1944), has written an interesting teshuva on the Shalosh Shevuos (the three oaths. Refer to [Kesubos 111a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111a.4)). Rabbi Rottenberg, in [his reaction](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1654&st=&pgnum=118) to some claims made by Rabbi Yehuda Leib Zirelson, says that the Yerushalmi gives an example of an redemption that is slow, and is being led by a tzadik (Mordechai in the case of the Yerushalmi). So, this kind of a redemption must begin with a tzadik.

Furthermore, Rabbi Rottenberg says (answer 4), that when the irreligious comes to having power, they are using it to incite the Jewish people away from G-d.

My own thought on answer 3 from Rabbi Rottenberg, e.g. that a slow redemption must have a tzadik leading the generation, could be based on what is explained in the sefer מוסרי קלצק, cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132075/27180), namely that the tzadikim are the ones we are leaning on, to guide us onto the path of Torah, and to cleave to them and thus cleaving to Hashem. However, answer 4 seems to be unsourced.

**Are there any sources (commentaries) that say that the nations of the world, especially in the generation in which Moshiach comes, will try to "lure us away from G-ds path"?** We have the false prophets discussed in Devarim, but this is not specifically linked to ikvesa d'meshicha.

I found the Divrei Yoel, [Parshas Chayei Sarah](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21045&st=&pgnum=474) who says something similair, but I am still looking for other reliable sources.

[image: Shu"t Yad Mordechai]

Refer to here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1654&st=&pgnum=118

Answer (score 0):

The author is not referring to the nations of the world, but to Jews in power who do not follow the Torah. This is extremely well documented in the Biblical accounts of the First Temple period, when kings who worshiped idols led the citizens astray, and the people did not listen to the prophets. Read the book of Kings and the latter prophets.

Also, the idea of a tzadik leading the redemption is the idea of Mashiach.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However, I was specifically asking for commentaries/sources that describe these two.